# Saving multiple images in an array

Tags: php, forms

I want to save multiple images in an array but because an image is an array my approach didn't work.

This was my approach:

```
for($i=2;$i<=$image_row;$i++){
    $image = 'image'.$i;
    $allImages[] = array(   
        'image' => $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION[$image]));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why are you defining your image in an array?

Why not simply:

```
for($i=2;$i<=$image_row;$i++){
    $image = 'image'.$i;
    $allImages[] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION[$image]);
}
```

Comment: That still gives me the error "Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"